# Lambda get data from mysql RDS but timeout

Tags: mysql, node.js, lambda, node-mysql

I am using Lambda connect to RDS with VPC and work fine.
I can get data from mysql successfully but Lambda will timeout.

CloudWatch log:

> 2017-02-15T18:56:18.609Z       [ RowDataPacket { userInfo: 'xxx'} ]
>       END RequestId: xxx
>       REPORT RequestId: xxx Duration: 300001.69 ms    Billed Duration: 300000 ms Memory Size: 512 MB  Max Memory Used: 22 MB
>       2017-02-15T19:01:18.306Z xxx Task timed out after 300.00 seconds

Handle.js

```
db.getPersonInfo("xxx", function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
    const response = {
          statusCode: 200,
          body: JSON.stringify({
            message: 'test',
            input: event,
          }),
        };
    callback(null, response);
});
```

DB.js

```
var getPersonInfo = function(userId, callback){
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
      var sql = 'SELECT userInfo FROM user where userId = ?';
      connection.query( sql , userFbId , function(err, results) {
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
        callback(err, results);
        connection.release();
      });
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally find out that pool should be end. And Lambda work find.

```
var getPersonInfo = function(userId, callback){
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
      var sql = 'SELECT userInfo FROM user where userId = ?';
      connection.query( sql , userId , function(err, results) {
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
        callback(err, results);
        connection.release();
        pool.end(function (err) {
          // all connections in the pool have ended
        });
      });
    });
  };
```

One more thing is that the mysql createConnection function have to run every time when lambda start. Here is [Ref](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=697093).

Comment: Once you invoke `end(..)` function on `pool` instance, you need to re-initialise it. Otherwise, it will fail.

Comment: I understand the callback is basically stopping execution, so I had callback after pool.end otherwise we were hitting the number of connections limit all the time, then I had callback after pool.end,  and from time to time we were getting PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT, as pool.end is basically a promise. So I moved callback inside pool.end, now seems to be ok.